# Magento Website Specific Featured Product

Tags: magento-1.8

I have added a product in both of my stores, but it has been set as featured in only specific store. And now when I try to get the featured products of another store, the featured products of other store also get listed because they belong to that store. Below is my code, any help ?

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->load(4)
                ->getProductCollection()
                ->addWebsiteFilter(WEB_ID)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', 1)

                ->clear()
                ->setPageSize(3)
                ->load();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4);

$_productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();

$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addStoreFilter()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', 1)
                ->setPageSize(3)
                ->load();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->load(4)
                ->getProductCollection()
                ->setStoreId($correct_store_id_for_website) // set store id here
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', 1)

                ->clear()
                ->setPageSize(3)
                ->load();
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: could you please explain a little, what has been exactly implemented

Comment: have you assigned separate categories for each website? Right? Then you need to set that category option **is_anchor** to **Yes**

Comment: @Deepanshu i have updated my answer give it a try